# how to access web camfor following code in google colab it

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
i have tried to acces web cam using webcam.read() and it returned false
where same worked in jupyter notebook
but i want it to work on google colab as we

```
while True:
(rval, im) = webcam.read()
im=cv2.flip(im,1,1) #Flip to act as a mirror

# Resize the image to speed up detection
mini = cv2.resize(im, (im.shape[1] // size, im.shape[0] // size))


# detect MultiScale / faces 
faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(mini)

# Draw rectangles around each face
for f in faces:
    (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in f] #Scale the shapesize backup
    #Save just the rectangle faces in SubRecFaces
    face_img = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    resized=cv2.resize(face_img,(150,150))
    normalized=resized/255.0
    reshaped=np.reshape(normalized,(1,150,150,3))
    reshaped = np.vstack([reshaped])
    result=model.predict(reshaped)
    #print(result)
    
    label=np.argmax(result,axis=1)[0]
  
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color_dict[label],2)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y-40),(x+w,y),color_dict[label],-1)
    cv2.putText(im, labels_dict[label], (x, y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),2)
```

For this code how do i read my web cam from google colab this code is working in local system

Comment: Google colab is not for GUI purposes or taking the IO from user. It is basically for the training model purposes or using another API's to take advantage of the GPU and TPU.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).